# Cannot increment the value associative array

Tags: javascript-objects

I've tried to increment the value of an associative array key. In the `"else if" at the end of the code. There's no error but it doesn't seem to work when I execute the code.

```
addItem(index) {
    const menu = [...this.props.menu];
    const panier = [...this.state.panierClient]
    let item = panier.findIndex((item)=> {
        return item.article == menu[index].pizza;
    })
    if (item = -1){
    panier.push({ article: menu[index].pizza, prix: menu[index].price, volume: 1 });


    }else if (item != -1){
    panier[item].volume++
    }

    console.log("yeah")
    console.log(this.state.panierClient)
    this.setState({
        panierClient: panier
    })

}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the equal operator

```js
 if (item == -1){ // here should be like this
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be === insead of =

```
if (item === -1){
    panier.push({ article: menu[index].pizza, prix: menu[index].price, volume: 1 });
```